# RoleManager MVC5/EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, role-manager

I started a MVC5 project with Individual User Accounts, I ran the initial migrations to get the database in place for users, roles et cetera.

I wrote a RolesController in an Admin Area, but from there, I am stuck. The first error was telling me to use roleManager, and include it in web.config. Alright, I did that according to an example I found on StackOverflow based on `WebMatrix.WebData`, but it didn't feel right, because it's a deprecated package on NuGet and integrated in `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData`.

And there the trouble started, giving more and more errors, which I Googled and fixed by updating `AspNet.WebPages.Data` and other WebPages related packages.

Then, running the solution happened to give me more and more trouble, because eventually all solutions happened to be for MVC4/Membership instead of MVC5/Entity. I removed WebMatrix.WebData and kept WebPages at the new versions NuGet got me.

I then happened to stumble on a new word of advice [found here](http://blog.luppes.com/2013/12/08/mvc5-authentication-roles-failure/). So I added that line to `Web.Config`, and everything ran happily ever after. Until I wanted to add a role, saving it took ages, resulting in this error: `Unable to connect to SQL Server database. (System.Web.HttpException).`

My ConnectionString never changed in `Web.Config`, so I am lost at what to do now. I hope someone can help me out.
This is the connectionString: `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ImpHer-20141111023559.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ImpHer-20141111023559;Integrated Security=True"`